# Change Font Size in Pop Up on Leaflet.Js

Tags: javascript, html, leaflet, font-size

I'm creating a map with Leaflet.js.

First I'm creating Polygons:

```
let Box1=L.polygon([
[429.99743, 505.374436],  // top left           P1
[428.393906, 505.374436],   // bottom left      
[428.393906, 506.9255941],  // bottom right     P2
[429.99743, 506.9255941]    //  top right
],{
//Set style for polygon object
fillColor: 'orange',
weight: 1,
opacity: 1,
color: '#641E8C',
dashArray: '1',
fillOpacity: 1
}).addTo(map)
```

Later on i'm binding Pop Up's with Informations to them:

```
Box1.bindPopup('<b>'+ knr[0] + '<br>' + wnr[0] + '<br>' + status[0] + '</b><br>Auslastung[%] <br> OEE <br> Geplantes Ende / Wahrscheinlichkeit des erreichens <br> Nächtser geplanter Start/KNR')
```

And Thats the result:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o1Emx.png)

I have the Problem that the text in this Pop-Up is to small. How can i change the font size.?